# how to create a view alternate for an special widget in a special zone in Orchard?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, orchardcms

how i can create an alternate `View` for my `Widget` so that it appear differently in different `Zone`? currently i can only use this pattern :

```
 Parts.Widget-Id.cshtml
```

can anyone help me create pattern like this :

```
Parts.Widget-ZoneName.cshtml
```

thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable the Widget Alternates feature first.